# Loop to create Object excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to get the unique value of each column in the range "RD" and display them in single column. I need to create an object ("scripting.Dictionary") where there are just as many as the number of columns in Range "RD". I tried this code but it resulted in "Run time error 13".

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Range(Me.RefEdit1).Name = "RD"
Range(Me.RefEdit2).Name = "OT"
Dim d As Object, c As Variant, i As Long, s As Long
Dim JK As Long
Dim o As Collection
JK = Range("RD").Columns.Count
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For k = 0 To JK + 1
    d.Item(k) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary").Item(k)
    c = Range("RD").Columns(k + 1)

    If d.Exists(k) Then
        d.Item(k) = d.Item(k) + 1 'increment
    Else
        d.Item(k) = 1 'set as 1st occurence
    End If

    For i = 1 To UBound(c, 1)
        d.Item(k)(c(i, 1)) = 1
    Next i

    Range("OT").Cells((k * 5) + 2, 2).Resize(d.Item(k).Count) = Application.Transpose(d.Item(k).Keys)
    Range("OT").Cells((k * 5) + 2, 2).Resize(d.Item(k).Count).Sort Key1:=Range("OT").Cells((k * 5) + 2, 2).Resize(d.Item(k).Count)
Next k

End Sub
```

Comment: Where does it result in the error? Have you run your code line by line to find out?

Comment: JK = Range("RD").Columns.Count would result in an error itself "RD" is not a valid range. Range("D:R") would be a valid range for columns D - R.  unless you have a named range called RD

Comment: @99moorem It looks like he sets a named range `RD` in the first line of his code.

Comment: @user3561813 yeah ignore my comment lol, I only reed after the dims. Coding practices dim eveything first

Comment: @99moorem I understand. It is also a bit nonstandard to create a named range within code just to use it in lieu of a variable. I gave an alternate solution using variables. Hopefully that more closely meets the poster's needs

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding some code below to help loop through a list, looking for unique values, and adding them to a new column. In my example, I enclose the entire functionality into a single `loop` for efficiency. I'm also adding the unique values to a new column in `Sheet2` starting with cell `A1`.

Let me know if you need any additional help.

EDITED CODE BASED ON A MISUNDERSTANDING:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim oDict As Object
    Dim rngToScrub As Range
    Dim rngNewColumnToStoreUnique As Range
    Dim oCol As Range
    Dim cel As Range

    Set rngToScrub = Range(Me.RefEdit1.Value)
    Set rngNewColumnToStoreUnique = Sheet2.Range("A1")

    For Each oCol In rngToScrub.Columns
        Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

        For Each cel In oCol.Cells
            If oDict.exists(cel.Value) Then
                'Do Nothing for Now
            Else
                oDict.Add cel.Value, 0
                rngNewColumnToStoreUnique.Value = cel.Value
                Set rngNewColumnToStoreUnique = rngNewColumnToStoreUnique.Offset(1)
            End If
        Next cel

        Set oDict = Nothing
    Next oCol
End Sub
```

---

Old code: Misunderstood requirements

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim oDict As Object
    Dim rngToScrub As Range
    Dim rngNewColumnToStoreUnique As Range
    Dim cel As Range

    Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set rngToScrub = Range(Me.RefEdit1.Value)
    Set rngNewColumnToStoreUnique = Sheet2.Range("A1")

    For Each cel In rngToScrub
        If oDict.exists(cel.Value) Then
            'Do Nothing for Now
        Else
            oDict.Add cel.Value, 0
            rngNewColumnToStoreUnique.Value = cel.Value
            Set rngNewColumnToStoreUnique = rngNewColumnToStoreUnique.Offset(1)
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: superb, your code worked fine but it just create a single "Scripting.Dictionary" so it produce unique values of whole columns instead of each one.

Comment: @agengsaputro  Sorry! I misunderstood your post and thought you needed unique entries across all columns. Please see amended code. It takes unique values from *each* column, and puts them all into a new column. Let me know if this more closely resembles what you need.

Comment: @ user3561813 great, thats what im looking for..thank you very much